# How to get all module's helpers?

Tags: magento-1.9, php, helper

I need to get all module's helpers, can you explain me, how can i do it?

PS: I see only one way - scandir() Helper directory and no more ideas.

Comment: You need all the helper classes? Or only the `Data` helpers? Can you explain a bit why you need them. Maybe there is an other way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you want a complete list of all extensions with there helper or all helpers from a specific extension.

With this code you can get a list of all extensions with there helper directory paths:

```
$nodes = Mage::getConfig()->getNode('global/helpers')->asArray();

        foreach ($nodes as $code => $data) {

            echo $code.' => '.$data['class'].' => '.Mage::getModuleDir('Helper', $data['class'])."\n";
        }
```

For getting all the available helper files from one extension, I also can't think of an other way than scanning all available files in that extensions helper directory.